# New windows update (28/08/2019) reversed the mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse

Last night I updated the windows (28/09/2019) with the update that Microsoft was prompting. When I tries to use the computer the mousepad was again reversed (fingers up, page goes down) and there is no way I can find to reverse it again. I tried the settings menu there is no reverse option. I tried the regedit there is no wheel options to convert from 0 to 1. The computer is a HP envy 14 if this says anything. 
I would realy appreciate you help.

Comment: Should be in Settings>Devices>Touchpad. It's not a wheel device.

Comment: Normally it should be but there is nothing there for this. I spent 2 hours of my life searching for anything but nothing.

Comment: There we several updates release for Windows 10 on August 28th, 2019.  Can you please edit your question to indicate which update you installed specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Guys I just found an answer to this problem. 
It seems that the newest MS windows update messes with the driver. 
It seems that the new options window of the touchpad settings doesn't have the Synapsis Touchpad Setting but only the ones the windows have.
So I rolled back to a previous driver and the setting appeared so I could dissable the reverse scrolling that was ticked as default.